# Single-pass search & replace

Tags: c++, c, performance

Does anyone know howto make a single-pass search & replace in a text? I'm working on a high-performance program where every micro-optimization counts. Following is an example that illustrates what I currently do:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

/*!
\brief Replaces all common character escape sequences with text representations
\note Some character seqences messes up the trace output and must be replaces
* with text represantions, ie. the newline character will the replaced with "\n"
* etc.
\returns The formatted string
*/
std::wstring ReplaceAll(std::wstring &str)
{
    SearchAndReplace(str, L"\a", L"\\a");   // control-g, C-g
    SearchAndReplace(str, L"\b", L"\\b");   // backspace, <BS>, C-h
    SearchAndReplace(str, L"\t", L"\\t");   // tab, <TAB>, C-i
    SearchAndReplace(str, L"\n", L"\\n");   // newline, C-j
    SearchAndReplace(str, L"\v", L"\\v");   // vertical tab, C-k
    SearchAndReplace(str, L"\f", L"\\f");   // formfeed character, C-l
    SearchAndReplace(str, L"\r", L"\\r");   // carriage return, <RET>, C-m
    return str;
}

/*!
\brief Wide string search and replace
\param str [in, out] String to search & replace
\param oldStr [in] Old string
\param newStr [in] New string
*/
std::wstring SearchAndReplace(std::wstring &str, const wchar_t *oldStr, const wchar_t *newStr) const
{
    size_t oldStrLen = wcslen(oldStr);
    size_t newStrLen = wcslen(newStr);
    size_t pos = 0;

    while((pos = str.find(oldStr, pos)) != string::npos)
    {
        str.replace(pos, oldStrLen, newStr);
        pos += newStrLen;
    }

    return str;
}

int main()
{
    std::wstring myStr(L"\tThe quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.\n\tThe quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog\n\n");
    std::wcout << L"Before replace: " << myStr;
    std::wcout << L"After replace: " << ReplaceAll(myStr);
    return 0;
}
```

The above code is obviously inefficient since it requires multiple passes through the same string. The  single-pass search & replace function should be so flexible that it can handle different arrays of characters to replace (ie. not just the escape characters that are listed in `ReplaceAll()`).

Comment: The algorithm you are looking for is called `KPM`. It's an `O(n)` string search algorithm that can be implemented to replace text in `O(n)`.

Comment: For performance, you might consider a c-style string, in which you check each character for possible replacement from a list, and output a new string as you go.

Comment: @JacobPollack Got a link to C/C++ source? If I Google for "`kpm c++ O(n)`" only this page of relevance pops up in the search result :/ ...

Comment: @JacobPollack The OP only searches for single-character strings. KPM is totally irrelevant here.

Answer (score 2):

You could use an hash table to store all the pairs of `<from,to>` and run over the string one time.

For every char do a check if it exists in the hash table and if so replace it.

It will complete the task in one pass.

Comment: I was hoping not to invent a new O(n) search & replace algorithm but rather to use something already available, but thanks anyway.

Comment: @Inge Henriksen Why so? If there's a simple efficient solution, why does it matter if it's a standard one or something you have to implement yourself? It solves the problem quite well regardless.

Answer (score 2):

For the task at hand you don't need any complicated algorithm! First of all, the "strings" you are searching for to be replaced are actually *characters* and distinct ones that (the more complicated algorithms mentioned in another reply are to deal with list of strings matched against a sequence). Moreover, your main problem is that you keep resizing your sequence all the time. You can't do the replacements in-place anyway as the string will grow with each replacement. A fairly simple approach should have **a lot** better performance than your current approach and, as far as I can tell, you are **very** far away from starting micro optimizations - you need to get your code do things roughly the right way first. For example, I would try something a long these lines:

```
struct match_first
{
    wchar_t d_c;
    match_first(wchar_t c): d_c(c) {}
    template <typename P>
    bool operator()(P const& p) const { return p.first == this->d_c; }
};

void Replace(std::wstring& value)
{
    std::wstring result;
    result.reserve(value.size());
    std::wstring special(L"\a\b\f\n\r\t\v");
    std::pair<wchar_t, std::wstring> const replacements[] = {
        std::pair<wchar_t, std::wstring>(L'\a', L"\\a"),
        std::pair<wchar_t, std::wstring>(L'\b', L"\\b"),
        std::pair<wchar_t, std::wstring>(L'\f', L"\\f"),
        std::pair<wchar_t, std::wstring>(L'\n', L"\\n"),
        std::pair<wchar_t, std::wstring>(L'\r', L"\\r"),
        std::pair<wchar_t, std::wstring>(L'\t', L"\\t"),
        std::pair<wchar_t, std::wstring>(L'\v', L"\\v")
    };

    std::wstring::size_type cur(0);
    for (std::wstring::size_type found(cur);
         std::wstring::npos != (found = value.find_first_of(special, cur));
         cur = found + 1) {
        result.insert(result.end(),
                      value.begin() + cur, value.begin() + found);

        std::pair<wchar_t, std::wstring> const* replacement
            = std::find_if(std::begin(replacements), std::end(replacements),
                           match_first(value[found]));
        result.insert(result.end(),
                      replacement->second.begin(), replacement->second.end());
    }
    result.insert(result.end(), value.begin() + cur, value.end());

    value.swap(result);
}
```

The idea of the algorithm is to have a single pass over the source string, finding all strings which need to be replaced and if one is found copying the section of not to be replaced characters and the replacement string to a new string being build up. There are few things which can be made a bit faster with some effort but this one moves each character just once rather than the original code which keeps shuffling the tail of characters not being looked at one character forward with each found character to be replaced.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of algorithms that are designed to perform string searching in linear time. Even though most of them are string searching algorithms, you implement them to perform string searching and replacement in linear time. Some preprocessing is required for their linear run time, be sure to read the pre conditions *very* carefully. The list:

- [KPM String Searching Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm) O(n),
- [Rabin-Karth Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin%E2%80%93Karp_string_search_algorithm) O(nm), however a really good average/best case.

To use these string searching algorithms to implement a search and replace algorithm, you would need to do the following (note, the analysis I have done is specifically for KMP):

1. Use KMP to find all occurrences of a given word in a sentence (keep track of their starting indices and the word it found). Store these in a hashmap, giving us constant lookup and insert.
2. Create a new dynamic string (consider a dynamic array ADT).
3. Iterate over each character in the sentence and at each position `i`, check to see if that position is in your hashmap. If so, find the corresponding replacement of the word (that is stored in another hashmap -- O(1) lookup) and replace it one character at a time until `j` - `i`, where `j` is your next position, is greater than the string length of your replacement minus 1, continue and repeat until you have iterated over the entire sentence.

**Remark:** For step 3 you are copying the characters into the new string as you are iterating over them one by one. If you reached a word, you copy the replacement and skip `k` positions, where `k` is the string length of your matched word.

... and lastly: free any memory associated with the original string and either return the new string or set the pointer equal to the new string.

In the end this should end up being `2 * sum[i = 1 to n] of O(1)` and hence linear time.

Comment: I already have a implemented a Boyer-Moore-Horspool algorithm for fast string _search_, now I need search & replace. So, you are not really answering my question here or is there something that I've not understood with your reply?

Comment: @IngeHenriksen, included pseudo-code description of linear time search and replacement.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue in search-and-replace is that it is generally pretty inefficient to attempt to do it in-place. Creating a new string is O(n) time and space; that's very difficult to do with an in-place replacement.

It is possible to do two passes over the string; the first one just counts the length of the result (or possibly constructs a scatter-gather list). Once that is done, the string can be resized if necessary and then the replacement pass can be done, starting at the end of the string and working towards the beginning. However, in my experience, that's a lot of coding for very little value. (Also, it doesn't work if some of the replacements are deletions.)

So I'd use something like the following (which uses C++11 lambdas, just because), although it's suboptimal: better would be to either sort the replacement vectors so that binary-search could be used, or -- in a case like replacing the control characters -- putting them into a vector indexed by target character (with a minimum and maximum) so that the lookup requires only two comparisons. (Or you could build a compressed table which only requires one comparison, but that's a lot of work, too.)

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

template<typename Char, typename String=std::basic_string<Char>>
class Translator {
  public:
    Translator(const std::initializer_list<std::pair<Char, String>> trans) {
      std::for_each(trans.begin(), trans.end(),
                    [&](const std::pair<Char, String>& fromto) {
                    from_.push_back(fromto.first);
                    to_.push_back(fromto.second);
                    });
    }
    void push_translated(String& res, Char ch) { 
      size_t pos = from_.find(ch);
      if (pos == String::npos) res += ch; else res += to_[pos];
    }
    String translate(const String& orig) {
      String rv;
      std::for_each(orig.begin(), orig.end(), [&](Char ch){push_translated(rv, ch);});
      return rv;
    }
  private:
    String from_;
    std::vector<String> to_;
};
```

The use of initializer-lists in the above is cute, but there should also be a constructor which takes a `std::map` or a `std::vector` of pairs or some such, because sometimes you'll want to build the replacements at runtime, not at compile-time.

If you want to play with the above code, here's a simple driver (for your application, you'd probably want `Translator<wchar_t>`):

```
#include <iostream>
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  Translator<char> trans{
    {'\a', "\\a"},
    {'\b', "\\b"},
    {'\f', "\\f"},
    {'\n', "\\n"},
    {'\r', "\\r"},
    {'\t', "\\t"},
    {'\v', "\\v"}
  };
  for (int i = 1; i < argc; ++i) {
    std::cout << trans.translate(argv[i]) << std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for better performance, your code is likely to be inefficient because of this line:

> str.replace(pos, oldStrLen, newStr);

This may cause either:

1. string reallocation (if new string is longer than the old one).
2. memory move operation (if new string is shorter or longer than the old one, so all characters after it will be moved to new position)

A dumb STL implementation could even allocate buffer dynamically for every replace.
Memory allocations can be slow, and can easily turn into bottleneck.

It might be more efficient to separate input and output string/buffer, and preallocate output buffer as string that is larger than input buffer. If you separate input and output strings, it will be guaranteed that your program will copy `inputString.size()` characters and there will be only one initial memory allocation (predictable performance). If you replace characters in-place, then there will be a slight possibility that no characters will be moved and no reallocations will occur AND a possibility that for every replace every characters in string will be moved multiple times (harder to predict performance) and new/delete will be called multiple times.

Replace could be done this way:

1. Preallocate empty output string (using `reserve()`) that is larger than input string.
2. Repeat until you run out of characters:
   1.1 Read few characters.
   2.2. See if they match something you want to replace. (might be very fast if you store replaceable characters in map/hashtable, which can have o(log n) or o(1) lookup speed).
   3.3. If they match something you wanted to replace, write new string. If they don't, write characters unchanged.

Also see [markov chains](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain)